# MapView and Autocomplete Can't get layout to work

Tags: android, layout, android-mapview

I can not get the layout to work for this.

I have a mapview that works fine with this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/rel_layout_mapview">

 <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
     />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/drag"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ss_pin"
android:visibility="gone"
 />
```

No problems, but as soon as I try to get a autocomplete above it, it does not work.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/rel_layout_mapview">

<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
     />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/drag"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ss_pin"
android:visibility="gone"
/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to do a layout with a mapview and a autocomplete above it.  The mapview must be in it's OWN relative view, because I have a lot of code specific to referancing the parent of the mapview for calculations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it simply by setting the margins.

```
<FrameLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dip" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/locationsearch2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter zipcode or address"
        tools:context=".AutoCompleteDynamic" />

</RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/rel_layout_mapview"
  android:layout_marginTop="50dip">

   <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
         />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/drag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ss_pin"
    android:visibility="gone"
  />
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```